# Backbone validate not working

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

Im just starting out backboneJs.

I did a simple example using VisualStudio2012.
I added backbone.

in my main.js

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    name: 'Mr Steel',
    age: 26,
    occupation: 'FrontEnd Web Developer'
},

validate: function(attrs) {
    if (attrs.age < 0) {
        return 'Age must be a positive number.';
    }
},

work: function() {
    return this.get('name') + ' is working.';
}
});
```

But when I go to browser > console. And type the following in .. validate doesnt even get triggered.

```
var person = new Person();
person.get('age');//26
person.set('age', -25);//sets -25
```

And it sets the age to -25. thats weird!! please help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to pass `{validate:true}` param to `set` method e.g.

`person.set('age', -25, {validate:true});`

Comment: works, byt i seen on video whr the persone doesnt passes {validate:true} and it still works

Comment: @STEEL yeah, in older Backbone version method `set` invokes `validate` method automatically. But now the validation is disabled by default.